# OnTriggerExit returning untagged after one successful tag return

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on **Unity3d** and encountering an issue relating colliders and triggers.
I have one 3d plane **parent** named Platform, one **child** empty object named TriggerChecker. A sphere tagged as "Player" moves over the platform and when it passes through the trigger, the OnTriggerExit method should be called. I have multiple platforms like the one in the screenshot. 
The problem is:
 For the first platform the collider tag returned is "Player" and its what I want, but on passing the second platform, collider tag is "Untagged". Is this because of using multiple coliiders, like one in parent and child. How can I make the collider work normally.

Here's the c# script attached to the TriggerChecker object, just relevant code.

```
void OnTriggerExit(Collider col){
    Debug.Log("Exit "+col.gameObject.tag);
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        Invoke("FallDown",1f);

    }

}

void FallDown(){
    GetComponentInParent<Rigidbody> ().useGravity = true;
    GetComponentInParent<Rigidbody> ().isKinematic = false;
    Destroy (transform.parent.gameObject,2f);
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that the `untagged` collider you're seeing is another platform.

Comment: But why would it return the platform's tag when it's colliding with the sphere (Ball)?

Comment: If there are *two* platforms, and one platform collides with the other, that's what you'll get. But the same is true for *all other objects.* My point is: are you sure that it is the ball that is printing the message you are seeing? Are you sure that the ball's tag is being changed (does it show this change in the inspector)?

Comment: Actually, the platforms are generated by Prefab, the game runs fine with the Prefab platform generation, but when I add the above trigger to the platform, this happens. I don't know why is this happening. And the ball's tag remains same in the inspector i.e.  "Player".

Comment: If the inspector shows that the player's tag isn't changing, then the untagged object is not the player. Print out the object's name instead.

Comment: Yes you were right. I debugged again with colider's name.  The first collider it detects is the Ball, and after that its Platform. Why such behaviour,when each platform has its own trigger and collider. How can I solve this problem. ? Thanks!

Comment: Note that [UnityScript](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) is a JavaScript derivative made for Unity. UnityScript != C#. Please do not tag both.

Comment: Thanks for the tag correction.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution,

instead of using `col.gameObject.tag`

try using `col.collider.gameObject.transform.tag`